# Axios get request not returning when express session uses connect-redis store

Tags: redis, axios, express-session

So I have this weird thing going on where the axios requests I make from the front end do not get the response I'm sending from the server, but it only happens when I set the store in express session.

I am making a post request to the login route like in this function

```
const logIn = async (formData) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    const response = await axios.post("/login", formData, config);
    // do something with the response
  };
```

When I make the request the server responds with status 200 and a user object. When I check the network tab in the browser devtools, I see that it is getting the correct response and the payload is showing the right user object as well

[image: server response in browser devtools]

However axios never returns and is left hanging forever.

Now here's the kicker. This only happens if I set the store on the express session in my app.js

```
import express from "express";
import router from "./routes/router.js";
import session from "express-session";
import "dotenv/config";
import redis from "redis";
import connectRedis from "connect-redis";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();

const redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.connect();

redisClient.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("redis client connected");
});

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

app.use(
  session({
    name: "qid",
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }), // RIGHT HERE
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "lax",
      secure: false,
    },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
  })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/", router);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

As soon as I comment out the line where I set the store, Axios gets the response and everything works perfectly. So I have to assume that the session store is somehow blocking the server response from getting to axios.

Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in the title, it's a post request that's hanging

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue, but I could finally solve this for my setup by using [`ioredis`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis) instead of `redis`.

I updated your app.js accordingly

```js
import express from "express";
import router from "./routes/router.js";
import session from "express-session";
import "dotenv/config";
import Redis from 'ioredis';
import connectRedis from "connect-redis";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();

const redisClient = new Redis();

redisClient.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("redis client connected");
});

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);

app.use(
  session({
    name: "qid",
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }), // RIGHT HERE
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "lax",
      secure: false,
    },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
  })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/", router);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```